# Failed to run webcenter components

Tags: weblogic, portlet, webcenter, oracle-fusion-middleware

i am trying to install oracle webcenter and some of its compnents like wls_portlet and wls_spaces, in order to deploy and test my portlet in Oracle environment.
i have first installed Oracle Weblogic Server. Then installed necessary repositories for those webcenter components through RCU.
finally i installed webcenter, and extended a weblogic domain.
Weblogic and webcenter seem like running properly, i can login to 
/console (Administration Console) and 
/em (Fusion MiddleWare Control).

two other component, wls_portlet and wls_spaces have their own "server", which seems like running. but non of the deployments under those two is working, and "server" replies 404 for every request. 
i have checked logs and found some classnotfound exceptions.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dms.wls.DMSServletFilter
this one is the number one of a long exception series.

Here is two screenshots which help familiar eyes to visualize the situation
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.ff1a4f9b3b.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.ff1a4f9b3b.jpg)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.08db701994.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.08db701994.jpg)

Comment: sorry for the image sizes, i couldnt make it bigger, all clickable link :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that WC_Spaces and WC_Portlet is running.  It is hard to tell from the images provided.  In the left hand navigation of the Fusion Middleware Control, expand the domain and right click on WC_Spaces.  A drop down menu should appear with the option to select Control -> Startup.  This should start the instance and in the right hand side the status will show green and the port.  For WC_Spaces the default url and port is http://localhost:8889/webcenter/.

Answer (score 0):

The default port of WC_Spaces is 8888.